# How can I hide Empathy's mail indicator icon?

Tags: indicator, empathy

Since I have configured Empathy, I have a new icon shown in the indicator icon bar. This icon remains visible even if I close Empathy.

How can I have this icon disappear when not using Empathy?

[image]

Comment: Hi orschiro, it's absolutely alright to change your mind on which answer is most suitable and "acceptable" for you. However, if you are going to change your mind after several weeks, it may be better to comment on why you had a change of mind so as to prevent any confusion about the change.

Comment: Dear @jokerdino, thank you for this clear guideline! I will apply it next time and leave a comment with an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by cl-netbox' answer, you can *automatically* remove the icon after `empathy` closes. This can be done by running (starting) `empathy` through a wrapper script. As far as I can see, this has no downside. The only *possible* downside would be that the right- click option to *open with* does not work, but that does not apply to `empathy`.

The wrapper would only run during, and only as long as, empathy is running, waiting for it to close, so the solution is very specific.

#### What it does

- When empathy is run (through the wrapper), a small script is started, doing two things:

  - look (check) for the `empathy` indicator to be visible, by the command:

    ```
    gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.messages applications
    ```

    This will return a list of current indicators. If the `empathy` indicator is not included, the script adds it to the list and sets the altered list by the command:

    ```
    gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.messages applications <newlist>
    ```
  - Then the script looks for the existence of an `empathy` window
    If no empathy window exists any more, the script fetches the list of indicators again and removes the indicator in the same way.
- Then the wrapper- script terminates itself, and your icon is removed from the panel.

#### The wrapper

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

key = "com.canonical.indicator.messages"

def hide_icon(icon, mode):
    # function to remove the targeted icon from the list
    current = eval(subprocess.check_output([
        "gsettings", "get", key, "applications"
        ]).decode("utf-8").strip())
    if mode == "h":
        try:
            current.remove(icon)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    elif mode == "s":
        if not icon in current:
            current.append(icon)
    subprocess.call([
        "gsettings", "set", key, "applications", str(current)
        ])

# run empathy
subprocess.Popen(["empathy"])
# make sure the icon shows
hide_icon('empathy.desktop', "s")

while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        # get the pid of empathy
        pid = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "empathy"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        break
    else:
        try:
            # see if the pid of empathy is still in the window list...
            wlist = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).decode("utf-8")
            # ...if not, remove the icon from the list and break
            if not pid in wlist:
                hide_icon('empathy.desktop', "h")
                break
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            pass
```

#### How to set up

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `no_indicator.py`
- Test-run the script with the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/no_indicator.py
  ```

  The icon should disappear if you close empathy. If all works fine:
- Copy the global `empathy.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications`:

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/empathy.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
  ```
- Open the locally copied file with `gedit`:

  ```
  gedit ~/.local/share/applications/empathy.desktop
  ```

  replace the line:

  ```
  Exec=empathy
  ```

  by:

  ```
  Exec=python3 /path/to/no_indicator.py
  ```
- just before (above) the line, starting with `Actions=`, insert the line:

  ```
  StartupWMClass=empathy
  ```

  This is to prevent an extra icon in the Launcher when you run `empathy`
- Log out and back in

Answer (score 2):

Install the `dconf-editor` tool ... open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

---

Open **dconf Editor**, navigate to <kbd>com</kbd> → <kbd>canonical</kbd> → <kbd>indicator</kbd> → <kbd>messages</kbd>.

[image]

Remove `'empathy.desktop'` in the right pane, log out and back in.

[image]

Now the Empathy icon doesn't appear in the indicator bar any more.

---

**Note:**

The next time you open Empathy, the icon will reappear and you have to repeat the procedure.
When you want to permanently remove the icon, you have to execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages
```

The downside is, that the Thunderbird icon will also be removed - so the decision is up to you ...